# Clock app alarms are stopping recordings

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I just found out from Apple techs that the clock alarm is supposed to stop all activities, such as making recordings, playing apps, etc. when the alarm goes off. Who else finds this ridiculous? I've had important recordings (work audio recordings, and my daughter playing music during a show, for example) get borked just because I forgot to turn off a not-so-important alarm. Ugh! Why should this behavior be normal? Why can't there just be a visual pop-up overlay with no sound when I'm in the middle of something? This should be normal.

Anyway, does anyone have a good recommendation for a replacement clock/alarm clock app that is basic and has customizable and non-intrusive settings for the notifications/alarms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ONLY if you set it up

Comment: Non-intrusive alarms?  I'm not sure I completely understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @fsb In my post I described how the alarms were stopping recordings. That's intrusive into another app I'm using. It's stopping the app. Not good. I have been trying out the Reminders app which does not stop my recordings, but is simplistic in sound choice (only one for all). My search continues...

Comment: @Debbitage I agree with you. I also just found this issue the hard way!

Comment: Absolutely agree. The user is actively doing a task such as recording something and the watch interrupts this task to display an alarm - without user's consent. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue recently (just moved to Apple world). I agree: this is so frustrating for photographers and videographers.
I don't know a solution (that's why I am Googling it, and here) but, I just came up with this hypothesis: Shortcuts - create a new Shortcut > Automation that when you open the Camera app, it will Add a new Alarm. This is ridiculous but, at least, when I open the camera (now), I can cancel from Adding a new Alarm and quickly glance at the ones already set up. I was trying to Disable All Alarms but that is not an option. Maybe someone could program it.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344117)